# How can I make rjson's fromJSON method convert JSON NULLs to R NAs?

Tags: json, r, null

I could of course solve this downstream in R, but I think that would be messier compared to just get rjson to do it for me somehow. Can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ideas:

1. Take a look at `RJSONIO` instead, and use its `fromJSON`.  The argument to look for is `nullValue`, which you can set to be NA.  I switched from rjson to RJSONIO a long time ago, after doing some speed tests and it also produces somewhat more readable JSON.
2. Consider reading in the text as a string, and replace 'null' with 'NA' using `gsub()`.  This isn't particularly robust if you aren't familiar with regular expressions (if "null" is part of a bit of text, you could end up dropping it, so it's important to be careful).

Comment: Thanks for the RJSONIO tip. I've always used rjson, but looking at RJSONIO now it looks a little bit more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like `fromJSON` in the **rjson** package does all its work in C code, so my guess is that there isn't an easy way to alter its behavior without altering the C code itself. You're probably better off doing the conversion in R.

You could simply wrap `fromJSON` in your own function that replaces `NULL` to `NA`. That would prevent your code itself from getting too terribly messy.